# Agent-based and individual-based modeling (Railsback and Grimm, 2019) NetLogo Business Model

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I am trying to learn agent-based modeling with this book, but I'm having troubles implementing the model from chapter 10. There has already been posted a question about this model, but a second edition of the book has since been released and I think the model has changed since the utility function and some values from the previously asked question don't match up.

My model does work, but when I try running the experiments in BehaviourSpace my results are widely different from those in the book. Has anyone else tried this model or can spot other mistakes?

Thanks!

My code:

```
globals [ decision-time-horizon ]

turtles-own [ location wealth ]
patches-own [ annual-profit annual-risk ]

to setup
  clear-all

  set decision-time-horizon 5

  ask patches
  [
    set annual-profit random-exponential 5000
    set annual-risk 0.01 + random-float ( 0.1 - 0.01 )
    set pcolor scale-color grey annual-profit 1 5000
  ]

  create-turtles 25
  [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    move-to one-of patches with [not any? turtles-here]
    set wealth 0
    set color red
    set shape "house"
  ]

  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles 
  [ 
    reposition 
    pen-down 
  ]
  tick

end

to reposition
  let potential-destinations neighbors with
    [ not any? turtles-here ]
  set potential-destinations
    ( patch-set potential-destinations patch-here)

  ; identify the best one of the destinations
  let best-patch max-one-of potential-destinations
  [ utility-for myself]
  ; now move there
  move-to best-patch

end

to-report utility-for [ a-turtle ]
  ; a patch-context reporter that calculates utility
  ; for an investor turtle in this patch
  ; first get the turtle's current wealth
  let turtles-wealth [ wealth ] of a-turtle

  ; then calculate the investor's utility given by its wealth and
  ; relevant patch variables
  let utility ( turtles-wealth + ( annual-profit * decision-time-horizon )) * (( 1 - annual-risk ) ^ decision-time-horizon)

  report utility

end
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that this model is different in our 2nd edition.

I did not check your code *extremely* carefully but I did not see any real mistakes. However, you are missing the code to update the turtles' wealth each time step, including determining whether or not the investment fails (wealth becomes zero).

The web site for our book ([www.railsback-grimm-abm-book.com](http://www.railsback-grimm-abm-book.com)) includes an invitation for people like you teaching themselves to ask us for the solutions. If you want access to them, contact us.